# Setting up an existing project on aptana (No Rakefile found problem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana

I just installed aptana, and i have the repository for the rails project.. So i open a new project and point it to my repository.. and it opens... But i can't do any rake tasks. Under rake tab, it says that "no rake tasts found. Likely cause is no Rakefile for the project"

But i can see the Rakefile in the project.. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have to change the Installed Interpreter path in aptana studio  , by default the aptana studio takes it own version of the interpreter ie  org.jruby . Make sure to change the path  to your locally installed ruby environment  .

In order to change it  go to  Windows->Preference->Ruby->Installed Interpreters

If you are  working in windows  Add a new environment  provide

```
  RubyVM home directory = c:\ruby
```

If you are working in ubuntu or any other linux platform  provide

```
  RubyVM home directory = /usr/bin
```

This makes  all the gems ,rake to available to your aptana studio . still if doesnot work 
second option would be, provide the rake path where you have installed in aptana .

In order to change it  go to  Windows->Preference->Ruby->Rake

provide the rake path =  (your-installed-rake path )

Good luck !

Comment: i tried both of them... my installed interpreter was already pointing to c:\ruby

then i tried the second way and pointed it to c:\ruby\bin\rake

but still not working :(

Comment: update your rake gems , can you post the rake version  and gem version

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late but I've encountered a similar issue and finally found out that there was no target in Rakefile, that's why this message is displayed. Just add one and this error message will go away.